# Macro to export date, category, and number of emails from Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm trying write a macro to export the date, category, and number of emails to an Excel file from Outlook.  The query I modified from what I found online is working to get the categories and email count, but I can't figure out how to add in the date.

```
Sub CategoriesEmails()

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application

Dim oFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim oDict As Object
Dim sStartDate As String
Dim sEndDate As String
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim sStr As String
Dim sMsg As String
Dim oExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ArrayKey As Variant
Dim ArrayItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim nRow As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Set oExcelWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set oExcelWorksheet = oExcelWorkbook.Sheets("Emails")

Set oFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder

Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

sStartDate = InputBox("Type the start date (format MM/DD/YYYY)")
sEndDate = InputBox("Type the end date (format MM/DD/YYYY)")

Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict("[Received] >= '" & sStartDate & "' And [Received] <= '" & sEndDate & "'")
oItems.SetColumns ("Categories")

For Each aItem In oItems
sStr = aItem.Categories
If Not oDict.Exists(sStr) Then
oDict(sStr) = 0
End If
oDict(sStr) = CLng(oDict(sStr)) + 1
Next aItem

ArrayKey = oDict.Keys
ArrayItem = oDict.Items
nRow = oExcelWorksheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Input the information into the Excel file
For i = LBound(ArrayKey) To UBound(ArrayKey)
    oExcelWorksheet.Cells(nRow, 3) = ArrayKey(i)
    oExcelWorksheet.Cells(nRow, 4) = ArrayItem(i)
    nRow = nRow + 1
Next

'Save the new Excel file
oExcelWorksheet.Columns("A:B").AutoFit
'oExcelWorkbook.Select
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show

Set oFolder = Nothing

 End Sub
```

The results look something like this:

```
Red 3
Yellow 4
Green 6
```

Comment: It's not clear what output you're expecting.

Comment: Are you trying to count all of the emails in a given category on the same day? Are you having trouble reading the date from aItem, or aggregating on the combination of category and date, or writing the date to Excel, or something else?

Comment: The output I would like is the same as what I'm currently getting but with the Date added to the front.  DATE|CATEGORY|NUMBER OF EMAILS - I'm having trouble reading the date along with the category.

Answer (score 0):

To count each day separately.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub CategoriesEmailsByDay()

' Run from Excel
'  in a workbook where there is a sheet named Emails

' Early binding. Set reference to Outlook XX.X Object library.
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim aitem As Object

Dim oDict As Object
Dim ArrayKey As Variant
Dim ArrayItem As Variant
Dim sStr As String

Dim sStartDate As String
Dim sEndDate As String

Dim datePeriod As Date   ' Loop counter
Dim sStartDay As String
Dim sEndDay As String
Dim strFilter As String
Dim oItemsRes As Outlook.Items

Dim oExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim i As Long
Dim nRow As Long

Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
Set oFolder = objOL.Session.PickFolder

Set oItems = oFolder.Items
oItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Dates may be impacted by local settings
' Enter as applicable
sStartDate = Date - 30
sEndDate = Date

Set oExcelWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set oExcelWorksheet = oExcelWorkbook.Sheets("Emails")

nRow = oExcelWorksheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Process each date separately
For datePeriod = sStartDate To sEndDate
    
    ' Must specify time or the date will be off a few hours
    sStartDay = Format(datePeriod, "DDDDD HH:NN")
    Debug.Print sStartDay
    sEndDay = Format(datePeriod + 1, "DDDDD HH:NN")
    Debug.Print sEndDay
        
    strFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & sStartDay & "' And [ReceivedTime] < '" & sEndDay & "'"
    Debug.Print strFilter
    
    Set oItemsRes = oItems.Restrict(strFilter)
    
    If oItemsRes.Count > 0 Then
            
        For Each aitem In oItemsRes
            sStr = aitem.Categories
            If Not oDict.Exists(sStr) Then
                oDict(sStr) = 0
            End If
            oDict(sStr) = CLng(oDict(sStr)) + 1
        Next aitem
        
        ArrayKey = oDict.Keys
        ArrayItem = oDict.Items
        
        'Input the information into the Excel file
        For i = LBound(ArrayKey) To UBound(ArrayKey)
            oExcelWorksheet.Cells(nRow, 2) = sStartDay
            oExcelWorksheet.Cells(nRow, 3) = ArrayKey(i)
            oExcelWorksheet.Cells(nRow, 4) = ArrayItem(i)
            nRow = nRow + 1
        Next
        
        ' reinitialize dictionary - to restart counts for next day
        oDict.RemoveAll
    End If

Next

oExcelWorksheet.Columns("A:B").AutoFit

End Sub
```